# ASP.NET MVC 4: Changing the Value of a Hidden field in Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **hidden boolean** field :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsTurkey)
```

In jQuery script I try to change it:

```
$("@Html.IdFor(x => x.IsTurkey)").val("False");
```

But on the post back IsTurkey is not changed:

```
    HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Search(TurkeyModel model)
    { ...}
```

Using jQuery as above, how do I change the value of a **hidden** boolean field in MVC 4 ?

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think you'd want to do `$(Html.IdFor(x => x.IsTurkey))`, also try not to mix server-side and front-end coding. Can you not get the ID of it any other way?

Comment: In MVC 4, $("#@Html.IdFor(x => x.IsTurkey)") is the correct way to create the javascript dynamically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you include a leading # in the Jquery selector, as the MVC HtmlHelper does not output it.

Comment: That did it, I will mark this as the answer once the timer lets me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure your exact code for `IdFor`, but you can simply do:

```
$("#IsTurkey").val(false);
```

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com Hmm, while debugging your post, what value is in the `Request.Form` for `IsTurkey`?