# ajax post call not refreshing my controller view in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a javascript function that sets two values (longitude/latitude) and tries to post back to my action method in the controller. My action method gets hit and I step through the function and then the view into the html, but my page never gets refreshed with the new view that the controller is calling. The latitude and longitude are being passed to my controller greate, it's just not refreshing the view. Any reason why?

```
function editLocation() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var name = place.name;
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lon = place.geometry.location.lng();
    //alert("This function is working!");
    //alert(place.name);
   //alert(place.address_components[0].long_name);
    var requestData = {
        lati: lat,
        longi: lon
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Results',
        type: 'POST',
        data: requestData,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Here is the form that had the original get call that I have partially commented out.

```
 @*@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{*@
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Search For Classes" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Submit' type="submit" onclick="editLocation();" />
    </p>
@*}*@
```

Here is my controller.

```
 public ActionResult Results(string location, string lati, string longi)
    {
        var repo = new YogaSpaceRepository();

            /// 1000 Ocean Ave
            DbGeography myLocation = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-122.453164 37.723057)");
            IQueryable<YogaSpace> spaces = repo.AllWithinDistance(myLocation);


        return View(spaces);
    }
```

Question - would it be easier to just use hidden variables in my form to pass the longitude/latitude data to my controller? It seems so but not sure if this is the suggested practice.

Comment: Your not doing anything in the ajax `success` e.g. `success: function(data) { // add the returned data to the DOM }`. You also never pass `location` so that will be null. And the dataType should be `html` not `json` since your returning a view, not json.

Comment: What would I put into the success parameter. Isn't it just calling some function if it succeeds? I don't want to call any function if it succeeds I just want to call the controller and pass the values.

Comment: But you said you want to refresh the view. Ajax calls stay on the same page (they dont redirect to another page!). The data in the success callback is the html generated by your method (i.e.`return View(spaces);`) so you need to add/replace that view in the DOM. If you want to redirect, then use a standard form/submit

Comment: Kinda a newbie so let me see if I understand. The controller that I'm calling (home/results) is going to go to a NEW view. So this won't work? Ok so my example provided has a form commented out, I should use that? But then how do I get lat/lon to that controller without using an AJAX post call? I read use hidden variables but that seems a little sketchy!

Comment: If you don't want call any  function  after success don't use from ajax...

Comment: Well I tried calling success: function () {View(Spaces);} but it doesn't work. It says it's undefined. I'm still a little lost. If I use a form to post back to my controller is there a suggested way to fetch the javascript variables I'm asking for and send them to my controller without using hidden html tags?

Comment: Hard to comment without knowing more about what your doing. Where do the values of `lati` and `longi` come from?

Comment: Its `success: function(data) { $'(#someElement').html(data); }` (assuming you have a `div` or other element with `id="someElement"` where you want to add the html returned by the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the form that you have commented out. Add in two HiddenFor helpers for 'lat' and 'lon'. Run the autocomplete, and then set the values of the two hidden fields using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665355/asp-net-mvc-4-changing-the-value-of-a-hidden-field-in-javascript).

It doesn't make sense to use ajax in this case, if you just want the user to search for a location and then be sent to another page. However, I would suggest loading the results of the search on the same page using ajax. It will look cooler :)

Comment: I'm trying to imitate airbnb.com when I do a search on the main page for some city like SF, the url that it takes me to looks like this airbnb.com/s/san-francisco--ca--united-states?.... This site seems to be taking me to a new controller (the 's') view right?

Comment: ? If you using an autocomplete control to select a location, then post back the location, not the latitude and longitude values (get those values on the server when you post back)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was going to suggest the same thing, but I think he's using a specific Google Maps js api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: @user1186050 I just searched airbnb and yes, it looks like they are taking you to a new page, or view in MVC terms. (although I'm not sure they are using mvc as their backend)

Comment: I am using places autocomplete to select a location on my main page just like airbnb. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by your comment to get the values on the server when yuou post back. Aren't they done in Javascript on the page itself? Here is what my order of operations are. 1. do the place search and get San Francisco. 2. get the lon/lat before I post to the server, pass all 3 data values in to my controller. I need the lon/lat to search through all other lon/lat values that I have saved in my db.

Comment: I need to pass the location string ("San Francisco, CA, US") as well as the lon/lat because I want my search in my db to use the location string as an indexed value to make my search a little faster so I don't have to check against every lon/lat in my db

Comment: @user1186050 Sorry for assuming you were a man above--I am usually gender-neutral. But yes what you're saying all makes sense, especially given your db strategy. Again I would use the standard beginform, retrieve the lat lon as you have described, set the hidden values, and then post to the server.

Comment: JUst one more question. SHould I be using post or get? Seems like I want to use get to show the parameters in my url, but maybe not? Advantages/disadvantages? Just like airbnb!

Comment: You could use either one. It sounds like you'd want to use a get, maybe to allow for bookmarking, and so users can see their search in the url. Possibly a good candidate for a separate question...